# My code is not looping through my firebase database

Tags: angular, typescript

The below code isn't displaying all my items quantity, it's only displaying the first item

```js
import {ShoppingCartItem} from './shopping-cart-item';

export class ShoppingCart {
  constructor(public items: ShoppingCartItem[]) {}

  get totalItemsCount() {
    let count = 0;
    for (const productId in this.items) {
      if (this.items.hasOwnProperty(productId)) {
        count += this.items[productId].quantity;
        return count;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are returning inside the loop, Change it as follows,

```
 get totalItemsCount() {
    let count = 0;
    for (const productId in this.items) {
      if (this.items.hasOwnProperty(productId)) {
        count += this.items[productId].quantity;        
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```